# How can I add more images in NSDocumentDirectory?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

First I stored image path from web service into SQLITE, and then I retrieve it back using local path. I am using NSMutableArray. I've successfully stored one image in NSDocumentDirectory, but I have one issue, How can I store more than one images in NSDocumentDirectory?

My code is,

```
if ([[[node childAtIndex:counter] name] isEqualToString:@"Column5"])
        {
            NSString *str = [[node childAtIndex:counter] stringValue];

            [Col5 addObject:str];

            NSString *myString = [Col5 componentsJoinedByString:@","];

            NSString *aString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://webserviceurl/%@",myString];

            NSURL *url= [NSURL URLWithString:aString];

            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

            NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

            NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:strCol4];

            UIImage *image = tmpImage;

            NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);

            [imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this line:

```
NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:strCol4];
```

Just use a different path component.